# Using PYMYSQL with no user/password

Tags: python, sql

Currently im trying to use this line of code to connect to a company sql  server so that I can export and use data frames.

```
from pymysql import*
import xlwt
import pandas.io.sql as sql
# connect the mysql with the python

con=connect(user="root",password="apoo06",host="localhost",database="ds")


# read the data
df=sql.read_sql("SELECT XXXX",con)
# print the data
print(df)
# export the data into the excel sheet
# df.to_excel('ds.xls')
```

However my work place uses a windows authentication in order to connect.

Comment: Are you connecting to MySQL or SQL Server ? Please [edit] your post to make the title unambiguous.

Comment: Okay, i believe ive corrected this

Answer (score -1):

Look use this code

CONN=DRIVER={SQL Server};Server='';Database='';UID='';Trusted_Connection=yes;

In UID put the user you use to authenticate in Windows.

Comment: This is not terribly helpful, because this is not Python code.  It's not clear why you would suggest a different ODBC driver.  The suggestion to specify the UID is good, but it's not expressed in a way that helps the asker.

Comment: I think it is clear from the connection example that you need to specify the user you want to connect to so that you can use Trusted_Connection=yes; Besides, he is using pyodbc, it is normal to provide an example with python.

Comment: Hello, im no longer trying to use pyodbc any longer due to the formatting and attempting to use pymysql. Do they have a similar thing?